# Understand sql joins and data type impact

Tags: sql, sql-server

If a sql server column is a string versus a guid, how would joins be impacted (assuming no indexes).   Would it matter?

Also, when you put an index on a string column, does it become as efficient as an integer column with an index?

i.e. when you put an index on either a string or integer column, is the resulting index built the same way and therefore performs equally?

Comment: The impact between proper indexes vs. no indexes will be significantly bigger than any impact the data type of the column has.... stop worrying about this - make sure you **have** the proper indices in place!

Comment: That's one more for the macros, marc

Comment: Having an index is the difference between being able to look up someone by name in a phone book vs. having to read every page to find  them in an unordered pile of paper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All other things being equal, less data is better.  And by `data` I mean **bytes**.

For almost all SQL Server applications, the tightest bottleneck is disk I/O, and pulling less data from disk (or cache) makes everything faster.

This is variable depending on your declared string length.  Bear in mind that `GUID`s are 16 bytes, and `varchar` are 1 byte per character.  `nvarchar` are 2 bytes per character.  `(n)varchar` also have a **2 byte overhead** per row to define the string length.

Space/bytes wise, a `String` is bigger than a `GUID` is bigger than an `int`.

The smaller/tighter your field definition the better, so `int` is faster than a `guid`, which is faster than a `string`.

Comment: And that's most important if you have **indices** which are additional structures on top of your actual data. You don't want to waste too much space there!

Comment: not all strings are longer than a GUID! any varchar(15) or less or nvarchar(7) or less, will be smaller than a GUID.

Comment: @KM - I had that caveat in there but must have edited it out.  I'll add it back in.

Comment: @KM - added.  Also bear in mind your string lengths in the comment don't take into account the 2 byte overhead per row for string length storage

Answer (score 1):

Without indices, the size of the column really doesn't make a huge difference, since SQL Server will have to basically do a table scan anyway, to link up the two values. Whether that's for a 4-byte INT or a 60-byte VARCHAR really doesn't make a big difference - that data is there in the data pages anyway.

But if you start using indices, **smaller** and **fixed-length** data (4-byte fixed-length `INT`) is significantly better than larger fixed-width structures (like 16-byte GUID / `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`), and much better than variable-width columns like `VARCHAR` - but again: only with indices...

Answer (score 0):

A string column will always have higher overhead than an int column. Indexes are generally some kind of hash, and a string (especially long ones) will always take longer to hash than a simple 16/32/64bit integer.

Scanning either index will most likely take the same amount of time, but the overhead of producing/maintaining the indexes will always make int columns win.

Comment: Then each string has to be compared, character by character. painfully slow for large databases.

Comment: and while you're doing this, the difference between comparing an INT or a string really pales against the general slowness of having to scan through the whole table - especially on large tables!